# how to create mapkit annotations by using data json data from server?

Tags: json, swift

I read from my server and print it out in my xcode project. But when I tried to represent the json code to show mapkit annotations according to latitude and longitude from the server it would not work.

Here is my structure:

```
struct User {

    var locaitonid: String
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double
    var cityName: String

    init(_ dictionary: [String: Any]) {
      self.locaitonid = dictionary["location_id"] as? String ?? ""
        self.latitude = dictionary["latitude"] as? Double ?? 0.0
        self.longitude = dictionary["longitude"] as? Double ?? 0.0
      self.cityName = dictionary["city_name"] as? String ?? ""
    }
```

Here is my viewController code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var model = [User]()

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let url = URL(string: "http://web server link ") else {return}
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let dataResponse = data,
                  error == nil else {
                  print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")
                  return }
            do{
                //here dataResponse received from a network request
                let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:
                    dataResponse, options: [])
              // print(jsonResponse) //Response result
                guard let jsonArray = jsonResponse as? [[String: Any]] else {
                      return
                }

                for dic in jsonArray{

                    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                    annotation.title = (dic["location_id"] as! String)
                    annotation.subtitle = (dic["city_name"]as! String)
                    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: dic["latitude"]as!Double, longitude: dic["longitude"]as!Double)
                    self.mapView.addAnnotations([annotation])
                    self.mapView.showAnnotations([annotation], animated: true)



                }


             } catch let parsingError {
                print("Error", parsingError)
           }


        }
        task.resume()


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var model = [User]()

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let url = URL(string: "http://web server link ") else {return}
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let dataResponse = data,
                  error == nil else {
                  print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")
                  return }
            do{
                //here dataResponse received from a network request
                let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:
                    dataResponse, options: [])
              // print(jsonResponse) //Response result
                guard let jsonArray = jsonResponse as? [[String: Any]] else {
                      return
                }

                for dic in jsonArray{

                    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                    annotation.title = (dic["location_id"] as! String)
                    annotation.subtitle = (dic["city_name"]as! String)
                    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: dic["latitude"]as!Double, longitude: dic["longitude"]as!Double)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       self.mapView.addAnnotations([annotation])
                       self.mapView.showAnnotations([annotation], animated: true)
        }



                }


             } catch let parsingError {
                print("Error", parsingError)
           }


        }
        task.resume()


    }
```

Comment: after adding all the annotations you would need to change the camera position to one of your annotations .